# How to hide a chart series based on the value of a parameter?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report parameter of type INTEGER with a handful of values defined (I'm using "Specify Values" to manually input them), it's a single value choice.

I have a chart where I have some series of data, each refers to a parameter value so I'd like to hide the non-relevant ones.

To do so, I set an expression like this in the VISIBILITY of each series:

```
=Parameters!MyParam.Value <> 1
```

To make it so that only picking the parameter value 1 will allow it to show.
(I also copy-pasted the expression in the Legend tab to hide it there too)

It doesn't seem to be the case: no matter what I pick in the parameter, all series of the chart always show up. It's like the expression is not even there.

The version is **SQL 2008,2012,2014** (I can't change it, this is a Dynamics 365 Report) and I'm operating in **Visual Studio 2015**.

Comment: ... tweaking the size of a tablix column and rebuilding lead to **some** values being recognized (with no changes in the expressions) ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you have set the hidden property but if you have set it on a series then you will probably find it affects all lines (assuming a line chart). if this is the case then the easiest way might be to filter your dataset or pass the parameter to the dataset query and filter of the values there.

As a test, set the hidden property to true (in place of your expression) and see if all series are hidden.

If this does not help, please post a screen shot of you chart design showing the Chart Data fly-out panel with groups and values shown.